# Angular2 vendor bundle with browserify

Tags: angular, bundle, browserify, vendor

Im trying to split the compile into a app and a vendor bundle to minimize compile time. My app is made with Angular2 and Im trying to use Gulp/Browserify to do the bundling.

The issue is when Im loading my webpage, I get the following error:

```
_prelude.js:1Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'
s @ _prelude.js:1
s @ _prelude.js:1
(anonymous function) @ _prelude.js:1
(anonymous function) @ main.ts:2
7../app/app.component @ main.ts:7
s @ _prelude.js:1
e @ _prelude.js:1
(anonymous function) @ _prelude.js:1
```

The code can be found at: https://github.com/IngvarKofoed/angular2-browserify

What Im I doing wrong? :)